# How to rotate (transpose) a 2D array diagonally (switch axes) in Javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting, matrix, multidimensional-array

```
[1][2][3][4]
[5][6][7][8]
[9][0][A][B]
[C][D][E][F]

[1][5][9][C]
[2][6][0][D]
[3][7][A][E]
[4][8][B][F]
```

I am hoping someone can provide suggestions on how to diagonally rotate a 2D array. So the first row becomes the first column; second row, second column, etc...

Any guidance appreciated.

Argh! Sorry, I forgot to mention: Javascript

Comment: This is called a 'transpose'

Comment: It depends on the language. In some languages it is a single line of code

Comment: you may want to try http://cs.stackexchange.com/  for more algorithmic and theoretical expertise, SO is mostly concrete code examples

Comment: Not sure the suggested dupe is entirely useful to the OP. Obviously the general principles apply, but they are asking about Javascript in particular.